# These dreadful circumstances bring out the worst in 'absolutely' everybody

Tags: adverbs, prepositional-phrases

> These dreadful circumstances bring out the worst in **absolutely**
>   everybody.

Might I trouble you to tell me why *absolutely*
 is between them? Why is an adverb placed between 'in' and 'everybody'? Could it be an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Absolutely" is an intensifying adverb. In this sentence it modifies the "every" in "everybody". "Everybody" is of course one word, but when the author wanted to emphasize that he really meant *every*body, with no exceptions, he wrote as if "every" were an adjective that could be made even stronger with the adverb "absolutely".

Other ways of saying the same thing are:

"... the worst in everybody - and I mean **every**body."

"... the worst in everybody, without exception."